# Username and password authentication for WCF service behind DMZ firewall

Tags: c#, wcf, authentication

**Scenario**

Client *<-- over HTTPS -->* DMZ firewall *<-- over HTTP only -->* WCF service

When a client tries to connect to WCF service it must do it over HTTPS (SSL). If it tries to connect via HTTP, the DMZ firewall redirects it to HTTPS anyway.
When a request arrives to DMZ firewall it is forwarded to WCF service over not secure connection (HTTP only).

I want my service to be secured with username and password authentication, so I tried to set up `wsHttpBinding` with mode `TransportWithMessageCredential` and custom `UserNamePasswordValidator`.

My web.config file looks like

```
<system.serviceModel>
<services>
  <service name="WcfService1.TestWcfService" behaviorConfiguration="WcfService1.TestWcfServiceBehavior">
    <!-- Service Endpoints -->
    <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingName="wsHttpBinding_behind_firewall" contract="WcfService1.ITestWcfService">
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost"/>
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="WcfService1.TestWcfServiceBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
      <serviceCredentials>
        <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom" customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="WcfService1.WcfAuthenticationValidator, WcfService1"/>
      </serviceCredentials>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="wsHttpBinding_behind_firewall">
      <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
</system.serviceModel>
```

And my password validator class looks like:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Security.Principal;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.IdentityModel.Selectors;
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens;

namespace WcfService1
{
    public class WcfAuthenticationValidator : UserNamePasswordValidator
    {
        public override void Validate(string userName, string password)
        {
            if (userName == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(userName));
            }

            if (password == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(password));
            }

            //TODO: get username and password from DB and compare incoming password with one stored in DB.

            if (!(userName == "hello" && password == "world"))
            {
                throw new SecurityTokenException("Unknown Username or Incorrect Password");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To connect to this WCF service my client-side code looks like:

```
TestWcfService.TestWcfServiceClient client = new TestWcfService.TestWcfServiceClient();
client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "hello";
client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "world";
Console.WriteLine(client.GetData(0));
```

and app.config of this client app contains:

```
<system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <wsHttpBinding>
                <binding name="wsHttpBinding_behind_firewall_ITestWcfService" />
            </wsHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="https://example.com/TestWcfService.svc"
                binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="wsHttpBinding_behind_firewall_ITestWcfService"
                contract="TestWcfService.ITestWcfService" name="wsHttpBinding_behind_firewall_ITestWcfService">
                <identity>
                    <dns value="localhost" />
                </identity>
            </endpoint>
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
```

The tricky part with wsHttpBinding is that the WCF service expects that all incoming traffic will be over HTTPS.

I want the server to accept both HTTP and HTTPS incoming traffic and do username and password authentication. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: I would configure or ask admin to configure the WAF to accept only HTTPS connections and refuse HTTP request and also redirect to WCF service over HTTPS only. Redirecting HTTP to HTTPS is subject to interception by man in the middle agents thus never recommended.

Answer (score 1):

You can add two endpoints with two different binding configuration in your web.config - one for http and one for https.

Something similar to this:

```
<bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>

    <binding name="wsHttpsBindingConfig" >          
      <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None">
        </transport>
      </security>

    </binding>
    <binding name="wsHttpBindingConfig" >
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>

<services>
  <service name="WcfService1.Service1">
    <endpoint name="wsHttpBinding"
              contract="WcfService1.IService1"
              binding="wsHttpBinding" 
              bindingConfiguration="wsHttpBindingConfig"
              address=""  >          
    </endpoint>

    <endpoint name="wsHttpsBinding" 
              binding="wsHttpBinding" 
              bindingName="wsHttpBinding_secure"
              contract="WcfService1.IService1" 
              bindingConfiguration="wsHttpsBindingConfig"
              address="">
      <identity>

        <dns value="localhost"/>
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
  </service>
```

Comment: I am not sure whether this solution will validate username and password.